# How do I run the louvain community detection algorithm in igraph?

Tags: python, graph, networkx, igraph

Could someone please provide me with a simple example of how to run the louvain community detection algorithm in igraph using the python interface. Is there any documentation?

Thanks!

Comment: The main issue is that my results from multilevel.community are not matching the results I get by rebuilding the same exact graph in networkx and then running this: http://perso.crans.org/aynaud/communities/community.py I went through the code and I don't see any specific choices of parameters.

Comment: Some of the processing in Louvain is random, so it's normal not to have the exact same results, even when processing the very same graph several times.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's called `multilevel.community` .

According to https://bugs.launchpad.net/igraph/+bug/925038 ... this functionality does exist it's just called `igraph_community_multilevel`

If you look in the github repository for igraph

https://github.com/igraph/igraph/blob/master/src/community.c

`igraph_community_multilevel` does exist and it's written in C. I'm not 100% positive this is the algorithm you want but it might be.

> This is great news! Thanks!
>   Is this functionality exported into R?
>   Why does the function bear a generic name (igraph_community_multilevel)
>   instead of the name which the authors gave is ("louvain method")?
>   Using the name "louvain" would make it easier for the users to find the function!

Answer (score 7):

### Here is how to estimate the modularity `Q` using `louvain` algorithm in 3 different modules in python (`igraph`,`networkx`,`bct`).

```
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx
np.random.seed(9)

# I will generate a stochastic block model using `networkx` and then extract the weighted adjacency matrix.
sizes = [50, 50, 50] # 3 communities
probs = [[0.25, 0.05, 0.02],
         [0.05, 0.35, 0.07],
         [0.02, 0.07, 0.40]]

# Build the model
Gblock = nx.stochastic_block_model(sizes, probs, seed=0)

# Extract the weighted adjacency
W = np.array(nx.to_numpy_matrix(Gblock, weight='weight'))
W[W==1] = 1.5
print(W.shape)
# (150, 150)

#* Modularity estimation using Louvain algorithm 
# 1. `igraph` package

from igraph import *
graph = Graph.Weighted_Adjacency(W.tolist(), mode=ADJ_UNDIRECTED, attr="weight", loops=False)
louvain_partition = graph.community_multilevel(weights=graph.es['weight'], return_levels=False)
modularity1 = graph.modularity(louvain_partition, weights=graph.es['weight'])
print("The modularity Q based on igraph is {}".format(modularity1))

# 2. `networkx`package using `python-louvain`
# https://python-louvain.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

import networkx as nx
import community
G = nx.from_numpy_array(W)
louvain_partition = community.best_partition(G, weight='weight')
modularity2 = community.modularity(louvain_partition, G, weight='weight')
print("The modularity Q based on networkx is {}".format(modularity2))

# 3. `bct` module
# https://github.com/aestrivex/bctpy

import bct
com, q = bct.community_louvain(W)
print("The modularity Q based on bct is {}".format(q))
```

This prints:

```
The modularity Q based on igraph is 0.4257613861340037
The modularity Q based on networkx is 0.4257613861340036
The modularity Q based on bct is 0.42576138613400366
```